# Get the data from UI and generate a Mysql query from the mysql using Flask

Tags: mysql, select, flask, inner-join

**I** have 2 tables in the database.

`Orders` table:

```
OrderID     CustomerID  EmployeeID  OrderDate   
-----------------------------------------------
10308         2           1         1996-09-18  
10309        37           3         1996-09-19  
10310        77           6         1996-09-20
```

`Customers` table:

```
CustomerID  CustomerName Country
--------------------------------- 
    1       Alfreds      Germany
    2       Ana          Mexico
    3       Antoni       Mexico
```

My UI :

- You can select first Table(Orders)
  `From orders there is a drop-down to select columns`
- You can select first Table(Customer)
  `From Customers there is a drop-down to select columns`
- Middle scroll down You can select type of join(inner,outer,left,right)

I am able to get the table names and column values from the UI, below is requirement
 I need to display (response) dynamically generated mysql query?

MySql query example:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID;
```

Comment: Maybe you can AJAX somehow

Comment: What about a `WHERE` clause?  You need it to make `LEFT JOIN` meaningful.  And `ORDER BY`?  And maybe a `LIMIT` that defaults to, say, 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's the python code that you can use:**

```
@app.route('/generating_customized_query/', methods=['POST'])
def get_generating_customized_query():

    details = {}
    details['orders_table_column'] = flask.request.json['orders_table_column']
    details['customers_table_column'] = flask.request.json['customers_table_column']
    details['join'] = flask.request.json['join']

    base_sql = """
       SELECT Orders.%(orders_table_column)s, Customers.%(customers_table_column)s 
       FROM Orders 
       %(join)s JOIN Customers 
       ON Orders.%(customers_table_column)s = Customers.%(customers_table_column)s 
    """

    data = [dict(k) for k in db.session.execute((base_sql) % details).fetchall()]
    return flask.jsonify(data=data)
```

**The variables which we are using:**

```
`orders_table_column` = Column which we are fetching from `Orders` Table
`customers_table_column` = Column which we are fetching from `Customers` Table
`join` = Join which we are using in the base query
```

Answer (score 2):

i am not understand your Quinton correctly. but I think this help for you

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(IN tab_name VARCHAR(40),IN _CustomerID INT)
BEGIN
SET @t1 =CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ",tab_name," where  CustomerID=", _CustomerID);
 PREPARE stm FROM @t1;
 EXECUTE stm;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;
END
```

you can call this

```
CALL test('Orders',2);
```

```
CALL test('Customers',2);
```